# Why Gmail, Dropbox have started using bell for notification icon?

Tags: notification, google

Recently, I've seen that **Gmail** and **Dropbox** have changed their notification icon and have started using **bell**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to understand:

1. Why bell?
2. Is it becoming industry standard?

Comment: What icon was it before the bell?

Comment: When you have million active users at any one day, whatever you are doing are pretty much industry standard.

Comment: @J_rgen Previously, it was just a box with number of notifications.
http://i.imgur.com/MgKPL.png
And about Dropbox I guess they didn't have any or something like inbox was there.
https://www.nsbasic.com/images/blog/deploydropbox1.png

Answer (score 6):

[Bells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_bell) [have been used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship%27s_bell) [for signaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doorbell) [forever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_call_bell), [really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_bell).

On that premise, it's easy to go for a bell when it comes to notifications, as they are just that; signals that something is happening.

A bell requires - maybe even demands - your attention, and so does a notification!

As to whether it's industry standard or not, [it currently doesn't pass a quick Google test](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1G1ASUT_ENAU521&q=notification%20icon&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=Y1D_UauZDsagkQXOu4HgBg&biw=1920&bih=931&sei=ZFD_UYPMJ4zvkgXdwIGYAQ)*, but as mentioned by others, Gmail's/Dropbox's adoption of this pattern might help.

On top of that, it doesn't necessarily have to be industry standard to be the right icon.

Edit: *if you alter your search to the word "alarm", which might be less contaminated, [the result does get a lot closer](https://www.google.com/search?um=1&safe=active&rlz=1G1ASUT_ENAU521&hl=en&biw=1920&bih=931&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=alarm%20icon&oq=alarm%20icon&gs_l=img.3..0l4j0i10j0j0i10l4.1309.2013.0.2155.6.6.0.0.0.1.172.256.2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.23.img..4.2.84.TjRSjkCMnDM).